# Get Python to look in different location for Lib using Py_SetPath()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, lib

I have embedded Python in an application, `foo.exe`.  When it runs, the Python is invoked and immediately looks for `Lib`.  The only way I can get it to work is to place `Lib` (Python's Directory Library of modules) in the location as `foo.exe`.

Is there a way I can redirect Python to look somewhere else, such as `Python/Lib` ?  I am not able to change `PATH` (This is windows) and I don't want to hack the Python source code.

Basically, I cannot get Py_SetPath() to work, and I have not been able to find any practical examples on the internet.

Update:

OK, this works:

```
  #define MYMAXPATHLEN 1000
  static wchar_t progpath[MYMAXPATHLEN + 1];

  wchar_t* pdir = L"\\My_New_Location\\Python\\Lib";
  wchar_t* pdelim = L";";
  wchar_t* pypath = NULL;
  GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, progpath, MYMAXPATHLEN);
  reduce(progpath);
  wcscat(progpath,pdir);
  // I get the present module path and add the extra dirs to access Lib code

  wcscat(progpath, pdelim);  // I add a path delimiter

  pypath = Py_GetPath();
  wcscat(progpath, pypath);
  // I add the paths that Py_GetPath() produces.

  Py_SetPath(progpath);

  Py_Initialize();
```

I also call Py_SetProgramName();  AFTER Py_Initialize();  I am not sure if all this extra stuff is needed, but smaller solutions seem to fail.

It seems that calling Py_SetProgamName() AFTER the initialize is very important to having the embedding call working properly.

Comment: If `Lib` doesn't exist, then maybe you could create a junction `mklink /J c:\...\Lib c:\...\Python\Lib`?

Comment: From the Python code:

"Py_SetPath() can be used to override this mechanism.  Call Py_SetPath with a semicolon separated path prior to calling Py_Initialize."

Answer (score 2):

Before importing the library, run the following line:

```
sys.path.append('C:\path to Lib')
```

Details can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: I think it has to be earlier in the process (a certain Python API call?) Python fails before a command can be sent to it.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work (on Linux) doing the following:

```
// method to inspect PyObjects 
static void reprint(PyObject *obj) 
{
    PyObject* repr = PyObject_Repr(obj);
    PyObject* str = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(repr, "utf-8", "~E~");
    const char *bytes = PyBytes_AS_STRING(str);

    printf("REPR: %s\n", bytes);
    Py_XDECREF(repr);
    Py_XDECREF(str);
}
```

.

```
int main()
{
// for our manually compiled and installed usr-local Python 3.6
//#define PATH            L"/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload"
//#define PREFIX          L"/usr/local"
//#define EXEC_PREFIX     L"/usr/local"
//#define FULL_PROG_PATH  L"/usr/local/bin/python3.6"

// for apt installed Python 3.7
//#define PATH            L"/usr/bin:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload"
//#define PREFIX          L"/usr"
//#define EXEC_PREFIX     L"/usr"
//#define FULL_PROG_PATH  L"/usr/bin/python3.7"

// for venv (which uses the /usr/local/lib python 3.6)
#define PATH            L"/home/me/venv_dir/bin:/home/me/venv_dir/lib:/usr/local/lib/python3.6:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload"
#define PREFIX          L"/home/me/venv_dir"
#define EXEC_PREFIX     L"/usr/local"
#define FULL_PROG_PATH  L"/usr/local/bin/python3.6"

// ------------------------------------------------

#define CHANGE_THE_INTERPRETER

#ifdef CHANGE_THE_INTERPRETER

// TODO : Look at using this: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0587/

Py_SetPath(PATH);

// change the built-in prefix/exec-prefix, in place.
wchar_t* wpPrefix     = Py_GetPrefix();
wchar_t* wpExecPrefix = Py_GetExecPrefix();
wchar_t* wpProgramFullPath = Py_GetProgramFullPath();
wcscpy (wpPrefix, PREFIX);
wcscpy (wpExecPrefix, EXEC_PREFIX);
wcscpy (wpProgramFullPath, FULL_PROG_PATH);

#endif //CHANGE_THE_INTERPRETER

// inspect the environment variables.  With the #define commented out above the "defaults" appear as indicated to the right hand side
wchar_t* xx;                        //defaults
xx = Py_GetPrefix();                //<prefix> L"/usr/local"
xx = Py_GetExecPrefix();            //<exec_prefix> L"/usr/local"
xx = Py_GetPath();                  //L"/usr/local/lib/python36.zip:/usr/local/lib/python3.6:/usr/local/lib/python3.6:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload"
xx = Py_GetProgramName();           //L"python3"
xx = Py_GetPythonHome();            //null
xx = Py_GetProgramFullPath();       //<progpath> L"/usr/local/bin/python3"

Py_Initialize();
```

some extra bits

```
int x2 = PyRun_SimpleString ("import site; print (site.getsitepackages())");
int x3 = PyRun_SimpleString ("import datetime");
int x4 = PyRun_SimpleString ("import numpy as np");

//inspect sys info
PyObject* sys_executable = PySys_GetObject((char*)"executable");  reprint(sys_executable);
PyObject* sys_version    = PySys_GetObject((char*)"version");  reprint(sys_version);

PyObject* sys_realPrefix = PySys_GetObject((char*)"real_prefix");  reprint(sys_realPrefix);
PyObject* sys_basePrefix = PySys_GetObject((char*)"base_prefix");  reprint(sys_basePrefix);
```

## Some points to note:

If you look at the Python module `getpath.c` you will see the following buffers:

```
static wchar_t prefix[MAXPATHLEN+1];
static wchar_t exec_prefix[MAXPATHLEN+1];
static wchar_t progpath[MAXPATHLEN+1];
```

Methods such as Py_GetProgramFullPath perform as follows:

```
if (!module_search_path)
    calculate_path();
return progpath;
```

...so it is possible to use those methods to obtain the buffer pointers and `wcscpy` the values directly into the buffers.  *Note this is currently only possible with getpath being implemented in this fashion!*

`lib-dynload` is needed to ensure that some modules (e.g. datetime) can be pulled in

Also note this approach ensures that the `.../python3.x/encodings` directory can be found, which prevents a runtime error within Py_Initialize